# Безопасность и проверки в написании API

Tags: java, android, api, rest

Подскажите пожалуйста как идеологически, а возможно и практически решается следующий вопрос. Пишется api к сервису на фреймворке лаварель.
Создается андроид приложение, которое будет выполнять post запросы на вышеупомянутый api (внесение данных на сервер) и получать ответы. Приложение будет доступно всем для скачивания из плей маркета.

Вопрос: как можно проверить входящий запрос на то, что он отправлен именно из приложения официального, а не любыми другими способами с целью "забить" сервис "левыми" данными.

Comment: Гарантированно - никак. Вы только можете усложнить возможность "забить" сервис. Например, заставляя ваших клиентов регистрироваться на сайте и проходить аутентификацию. Отслеживая подозрительную активность клиентов на сервере. Ну и тд

Comment: Единственный гарантированный способ - генерировать запросы на неэависимом защищённом устройстве с криптографической подписью, ключ от которой невозможно будет извлечь даже при физическом разрушении устройства (и то ещё не факт, что каким-нибудь рентгеном не просветят). Всё остальное можно подделать - было бы желание.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Посоветуйте пожалуйста стандартные способы или методы, которыми пользуются разработчики подобных api с целью базово защититься.
Как например базовые принципы борьбы с sql-инъекциями или там сброс тегов, как пример того, о чем я спрашиваю.